# Insecure Apache + mod_userdir configuration

Tags: security, apache2, mod-userdir

**TL;DR:** How can I enable mod_userdir in a secure way? (meaning: each user should be able to create and serve their content in ~/public_html but they shouldn't be allowed to read each others content nor directly - `cat /home/userX/public_html/file`- neither through PHP functions (`file_get_contents('/home/userX/public_html/file'`))

**Details:**
I have configured Apache with mod_userdir for offering my users the option to serve their content dropping files in their ~/public_html folder. In order to protect file access and to avoid that any user could read others' files, I have configured the following permissions:

```
/home/userA user.user drwx--x--x (711)  
/home/userA/public_html  user.user drwxrwx--x  (771)
```

I have added `www-data` to each user's group:
`usermod -a -G user www-data`
(it could also work creating a group and adding all users, including `www-data`, to it)

All the configuration works as expected. Any user can access its content from https://server/~user and they can't read any others' files:

```
userA@ubuntu:/home$ cat userB/public_html/index.php 
cat: userB/public_html/index.php: Permission denied
```

So far, so good. But the problem is that, as Apache is running as `www-data` and it has group-access to any file inside /home/*, any user can create a PHP file to read others' content using functions like `exec`, `system`, `file_get_contents`, etc.

I know that I can disable such functions from executing adding them to the `disable_functions` block in `php.ini` but I see this as a patch, not a solution. So it seems to me that there should be other, more secure, way of configuring this userdir-enabled Apache configuration. I have searched for a way to do this properly but haven't found a proper solution.

Comment: Maybe it's worth moving this question to Information Security forum? https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agree. I don't know if can I move the question myself or should I have more reputation points in order to do that?

Comment: If you think it's a good idea, flag your post as described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/how-do-i-transfer-this-question-asked-on-stack-overflow-to-the-math-stack-exchan